# How to nested eager loading in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

```
Class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :albums
end

Class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :musics
  belongs_to :band
end

Class Music
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :album
end
```

when I do this,
@bands = Band.includes(albums: [:musics])

albums are included successfully.
musics are not included.
bullet says "AVOID eager loading detected Band=>[:musics]"
how can I include musics?

Answer (score 3):

according this [blog](https://maximomussini.com/posts/mongoid_includes/)

> Although Mongoid provides eager loading support out of the box, it has
>   a few limitations:
>
> - No Nested: Only direct relations can be eager loaded.
> - No Polymorphic: Polymorphic relations can’t be included.
> - Criteria-only: It’s only possible to use eager loading with a Mongoid::Criteria object.

and also there is a [solution](https://github.com/ElMassimo/mongoid_includes).

Comment: Now, Mongoid >= 5.1.0 already supports nested includes natively!
I answered and talked more about this solution right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73558758/7644846

Answer (score 1):

Well, **Mongoid >= 8.0** already supports nested includes natively! ✔️

- Syntax

```rb
Voucher.includes(:created_by, booking: [:unit])
```

- Classes

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class Unit
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class Booking
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :unit
  has_many :vouchers
end

class Voucher
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :booking
  belongs_to :created_by, class_name: 'User'
end
```

The new **nested includes** is shown as a solution to [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-5473).

So, there is no need to use `mongoid_includes` gem if your Mongoid version is >= 8.0.